# Webview&redabilitywebview works fine in android not in ios react native

Tags: react-native, webview

I am using a inapp browser using webview and  readbilitywebview. it works fine in android but in ios the webview dosent display any content other than title of news and in readbilitywebview getting an error "invariant violation require native component rncwkwebview manager not found in the ui manager"

Using expo cli for development.

Webview:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView,StyleSheet,View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

import SimpleWebView from './webModal';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const title = JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('title'))
    const url = (navigation.getParam('url'))
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          backgroundColor="white"
          /*leftComponent={<Ionicons name="md-arrow-round-back" 
            size={25} 
            onPress={() => {
              alert('You tapped the button!');
            }}/>}*/
          centerComponent={
            <Text
              numberOfLines={1}
              style={{
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 'bold'
              }}>
              {title}
            </Text>}
          rightComponent={
            <Ionicons name="ios-book"
              size={25}
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Webview', {
                  url: (url),
                  title: (title)
                });
              }} />
          }
        />
        <WebView
          source={{
            uri: (navigation.getParam('url'))
          }}
          style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyWeb,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  Webview: {
    screen: SimpleWebView,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
},
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});

const Webpage = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default Webpage;
```

Redabilitywebview

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import ReadabilityWebView from "react-native-webview-readability";
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const css =
  `body {
    color: #2a2a2a;
  }
  img, figure {
    display: none;
  }
  h1 {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-color: #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
  }
  p {
    letter-spacing: .03em;
  }`;

export default class SimpleWebView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.continer}>
        <ReadabilityWebView
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
          htmlCss={css}
          url={(navigation.getParam('url'))}
          title=
          {navigation.getParam('title')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  continer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  }
});
```

workes in android but not in ios. Iam using expo cli.

[image: this is what shows when ReadabilityWebView is opend:]

Comment: I don't know how Container component works but you should wrap your webview inside a View and gives styles as flex 1.

Comment: replaced with view still dosent work.

Comment: Can you show your new code?

Comment: ok code is edited.